# Don't getting function arguments in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to call one function in codeigniter using location.href by passing arguments like year and option. The problem is if the first argument is null then the second is also null.

```
var year = $('#year').val();
var option = $('#option').val();
location.href = base_url+'controller/method/'+year+'/'+option;
```

I am trying to get this in controller this way

```
public function export_customer_details($year = '', $option = ''){

}
```

Comment: You can use URI Segment for that..pls refer official CI guide

Comment: Do you see the argument in url ?

Comment: @Drudge: The problem arise in this situation (http://localhost/project-web/crm/export_customer_details//top_100_won)

Comment: @Kunal: URI is also not working in this situation http://localhost/project-web/crm/export_customer_details//top_100_won

Comment: You had said that you had passed argument in location.href which is a link to the page . So, when you click that link do you see the passed argument in the url ??

Comment: why year variable is null?

Comment: @Drudge: How can I make sure if a situation arise like $this->uri->segment(3) is null and $this->uri->segment(4) has value. how will i get the uri->segment(4) value.

Comment: @Yoshioka: Because it is an optional field

Comment: @krishnakumar you are posting one thing in question and commenting next thing. Can you please make us clear what you are trying to ask ?

Comment: @Drudge:I am asking the same question. In my question year is an optional field if year is not selected I can send year as null, the problem arise while i try to get this arguments in controller if year is null it is not possible to get second argument. hope the problem is clear to you

Comment: If the argument is optional then why you are sending it from url ?? form hidden field should do your work .

Comment: to get what URI Segment contains actually get the whole array....
$segs = $this->uri->segment_array();

Answer (score 1):

You can try this but i think its weird

```
var year = $('#year').val();
var option = $('#option').val();
if(year != NULL){
   location.href = base_url+'controller/method/'+year+'/'+option;
} else {
   location.href = base_url+'controller/method/'+'0'+'/'+option;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yoshioka,  but I did it in aonther way.                                                           `var year = $('#year').val() != '' ? $('#year').val() : "All";
var option = $('#option').val() != '' ? $('#option').val() : "All";
location.href = base_url+'controller/method/'+year+'/'+option;`